# 2013 jeep wrangler battery issues

Tags: battery

my 2013 jeep keeps draining the battery when it is off.  any suggestions where to look?  the battery is new and holds a charge when not hooked to the car.  the dealership says they have no idea what is causing it.  they act as if they don't want to figure it out.

Comment: Any non-stock electrical work, like aftermarket headlights, stereo.....neon lighting under the vehicle, etc?

Comment: They probably don't want to figure it out. lol! Phantom electrical issues can be very difficult to troubleshoot. That said, I'm going second what @elrobis asked about aftermarket electrical equipment.

Answer (score 4):

Have you made sure that you close the doors properly? all the courtesy lights are off? Glovebox lights etc.

After those simple checks then check the drain using an ammeter and remove fuses to find out which circuits may be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem on my 2003 Wrangler.  Turned out to be the light under the hood wasn't shutting off.

The problem occurred after picking up my jeep from the mechanic for a clutch upgrade.  I drove it home and the next morning it wouldn't start.  Had a friend come over and jump start it and everything seemed to run fine until the next morning when it wouldn't start.  Jumped it again - same thing the next morning.  I'm not a mechanic or electrician but I happened to have a multi-meter.  Following a YouTube video I checked the battery after jumping it and letting it run and it showed a little under 14 volts which I believe is about right for a 14 volt car battery :-).  Ruling out the battery I figured maybe it was the alternator.  Again, thanks to the innerwebs I learned that you can somewhat diagnose whether it's an alternator by testing the battery with the meter when the car is off and when its on.  When the car is off and with a power draw (turn on your headlights and radio) the battery will read somewhere in the 12V range give or take a volt.  If you start the car and the battery reads higher that means its charging.  This is how I ruled out the alternator.  Perplexed I just looked around to see if anything electrical was on when the car was off and noticed the under hood light was on as it should be. I removed it since it's kind of hard to tell if it stays on when the hood is closed, and the next more the jeep started up just fine.  Apparently the light was not shutting off.

TL;DR - check under hood light.  If its not shutting off it will drain your battery overnight.